# Ind2Sub using matrix indexing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

[image]`[rowss colum] = ind2sub(size(matri_working_now),sub2ind(size(matrix_working_now),458,6));`    the 458 and 6 values have been manually given.

I would like these values to be read out from another matrix. How would I do that? I tried to iterate through the matrix and use indexing but it didnt work. matrix_stables is the matrix i need to use which has the values.

```
[nrows,ncols] = size(matrix_stables);
%for row = 1:nrows
%[column] = ind2sub(size(matri_working_now),sub2ind(size(matrix_working_now),matrix_stables((row),2)));
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean with read out from another matrix? do you just want to adress each column of your data-matrix and give them as argument to a new matrix?

Comment: @TheMinion: precisely!!

Comment: then you can just use e.g. `Mat(1,:)` for getting the first column (complete). SO if you want to give it as an argument to another variable it could look like this: `mat_new(5,:)=mat(1,:)` this would result in writing the first column from your old matrix into the 5th of the new one. Obviously the size of mat_new must be equal or bigger than the no. of columns.

Comment: @TheMinion: sorry for misunderstanding...i would need it like as shown in snapshot of original post (458,6),(466,6),...etc. I would need it basically in the (i,j) format. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do

```
[rowss colum] = ind2sub( size(matri_working_now),...
                         matrix_stables(:,1), matrix_stables(:,2) );
```